# Does Bruce Wayne have a middle name?

Tags: dc, batman

Does Bruce Wayne have a middle name? I have heard many different ones so I want to know if he has a middle name and what it is.

Comment: You might want to consider changing your acceptance now that the canon has changed to include a middle name

Comment: I believe it's Fountainsof.

Comment: Okay no wait, I've got a better one now. In an enormous troll directed at Commissioner Gordon, he changed it to "Atman".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bruce Wayne does not have a known middle name, but there are some common propositions for a middle name among them are Bruce, Robert, Anthony, Alen, or Thomas.

- Bruce: Possible if his real first name is Robert.
- Robert: Coming from Robert the Bruce, one of 2 names Bruce was named for by Bob Kane.
- Anthony: Mad Anthony Wayne, the other of the 2 names.
- Alen: His Grandfather's first name.
- Thomas: His father's first name.

Thomas, Jr. was used in several places as a name for a Brother to Bruce. So Thomas is the least likely. Alen is likely due to him knowing a bit about Alen Wayne which means he was likely told as a child and usually that comes from parents saying "you were named after x. That's how you got your name"

Comment: Surely Alen and Thomas are his Grandfather's and Father's first name, not last?

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for pointing it out ^.^

Answer (score 26):

According to a web article from *Bleeding Cool*, published April 5, 2017, by Rich Johnston, titled ["Lois Lane's Last Name And Bruce Wayne's Middle Name, Both Revealed Today (SPOILERS)"](https://www.bleedingcool.com/2017/04/05/lois-lanes-last-name-bruce-waynes-middle-name-revealed-today-spoilers/), since the [DC Rebirth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Rebirth) (May 25, 2016–November 29, 2017), Bruce Wayne's full name now is apparently (now anyway), Bruce Thomas Wayne.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Batman (Rebirth) #20](https://www.dccomics.com/comics/batman-2016/batman-20)</sup></sub>

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in the picture that the article is actually referring to.

Comment: When I saw this question I thought it would be Thomas for his father. I'm happy I was right!

Answer (score -1):

We know that Kate Kane is Bruce's cousin especially in arrowverse (Earth 1),
Kate Kane's(Batwoman) father is Jacob Kane and Martha Wayne is his sister.
Martha Wayne's middle name is Kane.
(Martha Kane Wayne)
So Bruce is (Bruce Kane Wayne.)

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! I'm afraid I'm struggling to understand your logic here. Wouldn't "Kane" have been Martha Wayne's *maiden name*, not her middle name? And why then would she have given Bruce "Kane" as a middle name? What evidence in the comics is there to suggest that she did that?

Comment: Can you cite a source for this, or is it just speculation?